# How can I make Ruby 1.8 downcase non-latin characters?

Tags: ruby, string, function, utf-8

I am using Ruby 1.8. It seems that `downcase` does not alter non-latin characters. For example:

```
"Δ".downcase
```

returns `"Δ"`

I know that in Ruby 1.9.1 and later, I can use `Unicode Utils` ([from here](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils)). I have tried it and it works ok. Returns `"δ"` for the previous example.

Is there an equivalent (or any) solution for 1.8 Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nash@nash:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux]
```

`gem install unicode` (https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode)

```
require 'unicode'

$KCODE = 'u'
p Unicode::downcase "Δ" #=> "δ"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that it is working. Have you tried that in a production application? What is your experience? And another question that might not be applicable. The documentation of this library says that parameters to the functions have to be UTF-8 strings. Are ruby 1.8 strings UTF-8 by default?